# I am unable to successfully test my controller

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-test

I am getting the following error when trying to test my controller. I know the error is being thrown by something in the security configuration, just not sure what it is exactly. `org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanNotOfRequiredTypeException: Bean named 'springSecurityFilterChain' is expected to be of type 'javax.servlet.Filter' but was actually of type 'org.springframework.beans.factory.support.NullBean'`.

This is the test class

```
package com.chama.chamaservice.user;

import com.chama.chamaservice.auth.CustomAuthenticationFilter;
import com.chama.chamaservice.auth.CustomAuthorizationFilter;
import com.chama.chamaservice.config.SecurityConfig;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.DisplayName;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcTest;
import org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockBean;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.test.context.support.WithMockUser;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.MockMvcBuilders;
import org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext;

import static org.springframework.security.test.web.servlet.setup.SecurityMockMvcConfigurers.springSecurity;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.get;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.content;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.status;

@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@WebMvcTest(controllers = UserController.class)
class UserControllerTest {
    @MockBean
    private WebSecurityConfiguration webSecurityConfiguration;

    @MockBean
    private UserService userService;

    @MockBean
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @MockBean
    private SecurityConfig securityConfig;

    @MockBean
    private WebApplicationContext context;

    @MockBean
    private CustomAuthorizationFilter customAuthorizationFilter;

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders
                .webAppContextSetup(context)
                .apply(springSecurity())
                .build();

    }

    @Test
    @WithMockUser(username = "254704760842", roles = {"PLATFORM_SUPER_ADMIN"})
    @DisplayName("Should list all users GET: /api/users/")
    void shouldGetUsers() throws Exception {
        mockMvc.perform(get("/api/users"))
                .andExpect(status().is(200))
                .andExpect(content().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE));
    }
}
```

Note that the test runner actually reaches the test class and the error is thrown at this line `mockMvc.perform(get("/api/users"))`

This is the controller under test

```
    @GetMapping("")
    @JsonView(Views.Public.class)
    @PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('CAN_VIEW_ALL_PLATFORM_MEMBERS')")
    public ResponseEntity<List<User>> getUsers() {
        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(userService.getUsers());
    }
```

This is my custom authorisation filter class.

```
package com.chama.chamaservice.auth;

import com.auth0.jwt.JWT;
import com.auth0.jwt.JWTVerifier;
import com.auth0.jwt.algorithms.Algorithm;
import com.auth0.jwt.interfaces.DecodedJWT;
import com.chama.chamaservice.config.ApplicationUserRole;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter;

import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import static org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION;
import static org.springframework.http.HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN;
import static org.springframework.http.MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE;

@Slf4j
public class CustomAuthorizationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        if (request.getServletPath().equals("/api/login") || request.getServletPath().equals("/api/refresh/token")) {
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
        } else {
            // Generate new access token from refresh token
            String authorizationHeader = request.getHeader(AUTHORIZATION);
            if (authorizationHeader != null && authorizationHeader.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
                try {
                    String token = authorizationHeader.substring("Bearer ".length());
                    Algorithm algorithm = Algorithm.HMAC256("secret".getBytes());
                    JWTVerifier verifier = JWT.require(algorithm).build();
                    DecodedJWT decodedJWT = verifier.verify(token);
                    String phoneNumber = decodedJWT.getSubject();

                    String[] roles = decodedJWT.getClaim("roles").asArray(String.class);
                    Collection<SimpleGrantedAuthority> authorities = Arrays.stream(roles)
                            .map(ApplicationUserRole::valueOf) // <- parsing every String to ApplicationUserRole
                            .map(ApplicationUserRole::getGrantedAuthorities) // <- converting every ApplicationUserRole to a set of GrantedAuthority
                            .flatMap(Collection::stream) // <- converting stream of sets to a stream of GrantedAuthority
                            .collect(Collectors.toList());

                    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authenticationToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(phoneNumber, null, authorities);
                    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authenticationToken);
                    filterChain.doFilter(request, response);

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    log.error("Error logging in: {}", e.getMessage());
                    response.setHeader("error", e.getMessage());
                    response.setStatus(FORBIDDEN.value());
                    Map<String, String> error = new HashMap<>();
                    error.put("message", e.getMessage());
                    response.setContentType(APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);
                    new ObjectMapper().writeValue(response.getOutputStream(), error);
                }
            } else {
                filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And finally, this is my security config class

```
package com.chama.chamaservice.config;

import com.chama.chamaservice.auth.CustomAuthenticationFilter;
import com.chama.chamaservice.auth.CustomAuthorizationFilter;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableGlobalMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    private final UserDetailsService userDetailsService;
    private final BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        /*
         * Setting custom login endpoint
         * */
        CustomAuthenticationFilter customAuthenticationFilter = new CustomAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManagerBean());
        customAuthenticationFilter.setFilterProcessesUrl("/api/login");
        http.csrf().disable();
        http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/api/login/**", "/api/token/refresh/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/api/users/save/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/api/daraja/register-url/validation/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/api/daraja/register-url/confirmation/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
                .and();

        http.addFilter(customAuthenticationFilter);
        http.addFilterBefore(new CustomAuthorizationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManager();
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem seems: you `@MockBean`ed too much! (`context` et al  do: *nothing*, except "gently returning a default value" (0,null,false...) on *any* method...)

Comment: Please start with something simple like this: https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/test/mockmvc/setup.html (resp. to your spring-security version)

Comment: Thank you @xerx593
I now have this
`@Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext context;

    @MockBean
    private SecurityConfig securityConfig;

    @MockBean
    private WebSecurityConfiguration webSecurityConfiguration;

    @MockBean
    private UserServiceImpl userService;

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders
                .webAppContextSetup(context)
                .apply(springSecurity())
                .build();
    }`
But mockMvc is now null

Comment: The null pointer was because I did not annotate MockMvc with `@Autowired`, but after doing this I end up where I started.

Comment: In the linked example: WebApplicationContext *is autowired*! MockMvc *is not*! (but setup "before each"(test))

Comment: Ok I understand, makes sense. Any ideas why it is null in my case ?

Comment: Ok I understand, makes sense. Moved mockMvc from setup to test class and removed auto wired annotation. Back to square one.

Comment: i recommend that you use the built in spring security JWT features https://thomasandolf.medium.com/spring-security-jwts-getting-started-ebdb4e4f1dd1